# Curiosity, Minimal transaction accepted as valid? (zero input/ zero output)

Tags: transactions, mining-theory, transaction-verification

```
$ bitcoin-cli decoderawtransaction 00000000000000000000
{
  "txid": "f702453dd03b0f055e5437d76128141803984fb10acb85fc3b2184fae2f3fa78",
  "hash": "f702453dd03b0f055e5437d76128141803984fb10acb85fc3b2184fae2f3fa78",
  "version": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "vsize": 10,
  "weight": 40,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
  ],
  "vout": [
  ]
}
```

I assume this wouldn't make it into the mempool or be relayed, but if a miner decided for some odd reason to mine a transaction like this, would it be valid? or would other miners reject it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take the transaction's structure :

- 00000000 (version)
- 00 (nInputs)
- 00 (nOutputs)
- 00000000 (locktime)

Of course, that's a good question, and your transaction's structure is correct. But,this transaction is going to be rejected. This transaction must have a version equals to 1. This must be required. In Bitcoin, it doesn't exist a transaction with a version equals to 0. In addition, a transaction must have 1 input and 1 output at last.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

No, it would be invalid. Every transaction must have at least one input and at least one output.